# Why doesn't my opacity mask fully hide my object?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transparency, mask

I've got a problem with masking. I've made an object and masked it over. The masking effect is visible, but it should go behind the object.  The transparent part should be at 0% visibility, but somehow it's still visible and I'm not sure why. How do I fully hide this part of the object?

[image]

Comment: Is your mask 100% opaque?

Comment: what that mean?

Comment: in your screenshot, the blue path is selected (orange border). the settings relate to it. if you would click on the black mask you could see the mask opacity.

Comment: Yes @Vincent that was it, didn't know about that. Thank you both now it's working :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either your mask opacity is not 100% or the colour you use isn't fully black.

Especially if you work in RGB and you chose the standard black swatch, it is possible that it is instead a very dark gray (actually CMYK black), which translates to barely but still visible in masking.

Change the colour of the masking black object to actual RGB `(0,0,0)`. If that doesn't work, check your mask opacity.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it has anything to do with the mask itself. The yellow (label?) kind of thing, is it a linked or placed object? Check in Photoshop the transparency, it probably is set to 90% percent or so, or the Photoshop mask is a bit shimmy.

Comment: Hi Captain, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. As you can see from the question title, the poster is using Illustrator, not Photoshop. Additionally, they included a screenshot where you can see the opacity is at 100%. Please try to improve your answer or remove it if you feel like it's no longer required. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: Hi there, I get your point, but do not totally agree; the pixels in the screenshot tell me there is a placed or linked object on the illustrator canvas, the orange plane. On top of that a blue line and several other strokes have been drawn in Illustrator. The opacity in Illustrator might be set to 100% but when the placed object is (semi)transparent, it is visible in Illustrator as well. A well, I was just passing by.. Cheers, Flo